Trying to setup Kafka on windows and getting 'wmic' is not recognized error
I am trying to setup Kafka (version - kafka_2.13-3.9.0.tgz) on windows 11 and zookeeper is running smoothly on windows but kafka server is not starting up..
When i try to execute kafka-server-start.bat file using below given command
C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties


it gives me following error
**
'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
please tell me what this error is about and how can i solve this error??

Almost certainly the directory that contains wmic is not listed in the %PATH% in the environment that is running in kafka-server-start.bat. Try opening a powershell command line and running Get-Command wmic . WIth luck you'll see the full path and you can add just the directory names (leave out wmic.exe) to the PATH. You'll have to search how to do that on your own. Good luck.
